# When a Warlock casts an Animus, is it still an Animus?

Tags: warmachine, hordes

So, I was playing a friend who plays a lot of Hordes yesterday, and he mentioned that when his Warlock casts an Animus as a spell, it still counts as an Animus.  This means that it cannot be cast on a model that already has an animus on it.  Is this true?

As an example, Say I am playing Legion.  I have a Carnivean and a Stinger in my battlegroup, and I want to cast the Stinger's animus (to get Bushwack) and the Carnivean's animus (to get the +2 armor).  Can I have both of them on me at the same time?  Or, as an even better example, say I have a Shredder in my battle group as well, and I want his animus up on my Warlock along with my Carnivean's animus - is that legal to do?  When I read the text of the Hordes rules, it did not seem clear to me.

Comment: I tried to add a "Hordes" tag, but I was unable to since I do not have enough reputation yet.  Can someone please edit it and add it for me?  Thanks!

Comment: Took care of that for you!

Comment: No problem - welcome to the site!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A model can have only one friendly animus in play on it at time. If another friendly animus is cast on a model, th eolder friendly animus expires and is replaced by the new one when the affected model is hit by the animus. This applies to animi used by warbeasts as well as those cast as spell. 
cit from the quickstart rules pag 4 right column ANIMI block.

To answer your question your friend is right :)

Comment: I figured he was - he usually is on Hordes rules.  Just thought I would get a second opinion.  :)  Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Technically he isn't right. The OP said "can't be cast if ...", you instead said "if it is cast ... it overwrites the previous one". ;)